# EF Code First Duplicate child relationships

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

I have a Person table that I want to be mapped to multiple foreign keys in a Usage table. Something like this:

```
public class Usage{
    int Id;
    int OwnerId;
    int CreatedBy;

    public virtual Person Owner;
    public virtual Person Creator;
 }

public class Person{
    int Id;
    string Name;
}
```

Now I would like to use Fluent API so I can reference the properties Owner and Creator within an instance of the Usage table. Everything I read says you have to create relationships between both classes (e.g. also map a virtual collection back to the Usage table in the Person table) but I don't want to do that. I don't need a two way relationship. I just want to say that OwnerId and CreatedBy maps to the Person table and load it in memory.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Usage>()
    .WithOptional(x=>x.Owner).ForeignKey(x=>x.OwnerId)
    .WithRequired(x=>x.Creator).ForeignKey(x=>x.CreatedBy)
```

Is this possible to do? I have a ton of relationships to the Person table and I don't want clutter it up with a bunch of virtual collections that I'll never use.

Thanks!

Comment: What result do you have currently? In database first it's possible to do so (there are 2 checkboxes on each side of entity to allow to create the corresponding navigation properties), so I think it's possible with code configuration.

Comment: yup, this is certainly possible. this fluent API mapping is incorrect though, WithRequired()/WithOptional()/WithMany() are used to map inverse navigation properties, you should use HasRequired()/HasOptional(). Also, you might have to tell EF you don't want inverse navigation properties, using the parameterless WithOptional()/WithRequired() overloads.